# Rapid PHP application development?

Tags: php, rad

What options are there for really fast PHP application development?

I'm developing mostly admin pages for customers and recently I've been looking into ExtJS which seems nice too. But it's a steep learning curve so I think I'm going to pass this one. Right now it doesn't seem easy but it looks nice because it has so many options for creating nice editable tables etc...

When I was young applications like Visual Basic and Delphi were there to create a PC app very very quickly.

But doesn't there exist something that would allow creating applications visually for PHP too?

Or what do you use for creating easy PHP application forms and tables with validation etc...

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Studio for PHP](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/php) is an option to consider. It is a set of UI components that can be used to build PHP applications in a rapid manner.

The whole product is vailable for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

[image: Essential Studio for PHP]

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Answer (score 1):

Try [PHPRad](https://phprad.com/info/features)

In my opinion it is a great tool for rapid development of php web applications with a mysql or MariaDB database.

The learning curve is very simple, in less than a week I mastered the tool completely.

[image: The Advance Rapid Application Development Environment with numerous options that helps your generate your application with drag and drop and few clicks]

Answer (score 1):

Check out Codejig https://www.codejig.com/en/rad/
It is really an option when it omes to RAD development.they have free trial of creation an app. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try Radsystems, I think its owned by the developers of PHPRad, quite easy to use and you can develop in PHP, Python, C#, Node, Vue

visit: http://radsystems.io/